# Efficient Data Structures in Maple

Tags: performance, maple

I'm working with a large amount of data in Maple and I need to know the most efficient way to store it. I started with lists, but I quickly learned how inefficient those are so I have since replaced them. Now I'm using a mixture of Arrays (for structures with a fixed length) and tables (for structures with variable length), but my code actually runs significantly slower than it did when I was only using lists.

So here are my questions:

- What is the most efficient data structure to use in Maple for a static-length set of data? for a variable-length set?
- Are there any "gotchas" I need to be aware of when using these structures as parameters in a recursive proc? If using Arrays or tables, does each one need to be copied for each iteration to avoid clobbering data?

Comment: what do you mean by efficiency? adding data or selecting?

Comment: I have some data structures that I need only to initialize and then reference later with or without modification (I'm currently using arrays for these), and other structures where I need to be able to add, remove, and modify entries (currently using tables for these). The need for efficiency comes from the fact that these modifications/additions/etc are all happening within nested for loops and recursive procs.

Comment: I recommend that you post your questions and your code (both the lists version and the Arrays/tables version) on www.mapleprimes.com. Lists are only inefficient if you add the elements one (or a few) at a time. Arrays can be stretched (variable length) very efficiently. I don't think that they can be shrunk. The most important factor in answering your question is probably whether you need to add the data to the structure one piece at a time.

Comment: What kind of data is stored in these structures? Floating-point data that fits in double-precision is often well stored (and accessed) in Array/Matrix/Vector created with the datatype=float[8] option. Also, you write that you have a large amount of data, but it's unclear whether you intend many small structure or a few large structures. Very small lists can behave "better" than very small Arrays. Commands which use in-place semantics are documented as such and often only do so when an optional argument forces it. More specifics about the code would help toward giving more concrete advice.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. I understand how much easier it would be to look at the code, but I can't post it due to privacy concerns. I will give as much detail as I can.
Data is being added one at a time in all structures that need to be flexible, so it sounds like lists are indeed inefficient. Plus, my setup falls under the category of "a few large structures", where the structures can get so large that Maple gave a size-limit error when I was using lists ("Error, assigning to a long list, please use Arrays"). As for variable type, all the data in the larger structures are integer.

Comment: You might be able to get a bit of memory savings by using the narrowest integer datatype that can hold your data. Eg, datatype=integer[4], or datatype=integer[1], etc. That index value multiplied by 8 bits means integer[4]=32bit. (So integer[1] is only adequate for values 0 or 1, etc.) Now, the question remains as to why the code is now slower than it was when using only lists. Perhaps the code, or commands it calls, converts some subselection of data to lists on the fly at some point? Do you call `indices()` or `entries()` on the tables often?

Comment: And pardon if this doesn't apply: if you have Arrays with more than one dimension then always access into it like A[i,j] and not A[i][j] since the latter creates A[i] as a temporary garbage structure on each such call.

Comment: Actually, I do have multidimensional arrays that I've been referencing with A[i][j], and I had no idea it behaved that way. I'll definitely change those to A[i,j], and I can certainly try setting the datatype for my arrays as well. I don't have any calls to `indices()` or `entries()`, but I do use `EqualEntries()`; would that cause any issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can wrap this one up now. I made a few performance improvements, mostly just small tweaks that only helped a bit, but I did manage a big improvement by removing as many instances of the copy command as I could (I used it on arrays and tables). It turns out this is what was causing my array/table implementation to be slower than my list-only implementation. But the code still didn't run as fast as I needed, so I re-wrote it in C#. That's probably not the best solution for "how to improve Maple efficiency", but it sure does run a lot faster now.